# Why should I upgrade my app to the latest Facebook API Graph v2.2 to v17?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was searching about this without success so I want to know your opinions, I'm a newbie in Facebook SDK and APIs. I'll appreciate your knowledge about this.

I found this guide but It doesn't respond the Why question https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/api-upgrade

I researched a lot in order to find the answer

Comment: annoyingly, API's get upgraded and what's worse, old ones get deprecated. see also [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog) for some dates regarding this specific api.